# Use content from another list in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to do 5 lists that have the same colums and I want to create one list that will contain all the data from the 5 other lists.
How can I do that?
I just can't find a way to do that..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Designer workflow which will run when item is created in any of  those 5 lists.  Add step "Create List Item" , which will create a list item in the "Aggregated List(Which should contain data from all the 5 lists)". In this way the "Aggregated List" will contains all the data from other 5 lists.

Since the 5 lists are having same columns you can create those 5 lists with a common content type and create 1 reusable Workflow which will run on that Content Type.Associate this reusable workflow to each of that 5 lists.
Below is link to create reusable workflow:
http://plexhosted.com/billing/knowledgebase/255/How-to-create-a-reusable-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-SharePoint-2010.html

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for such design? I do not know exact scenario, but I would consider to create one list and then 5 views for that list ..